# Crystal Reports, Adding an Additional Page Based on a Formula Field Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

How would you go about adding an additional page for a Crystal Report based on a formula value (any formula might do). I'm new to Crystal Reports so please have patience with my lack of report details.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you want on this additional page, but generally speaking i would probably created a subreport and place it in the last report footer section. Enable the `new page before` attribute of that report footer section and conditionally suppress it using your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Boolean parameter field named 'Show Last Page'.

Insert a second Report Footer section (right click gutter and select Insert Section Below)

Right click new section (Report Footerb) and choose Section Expert...

Enable the footer's `New Page Before` property

Finally, add a conditional formula to the footer's `Suppress (No Drill- Down)` property and add `Not({?Show Last Page})` to its text.

Answer (score 0):

Simply Right click on any section of report and then go into Section expert option

Now go to your desire section and then checked new page after option and add your formula.